# Couldn't locate .ndf files of new file groups added

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

When I run this statement in SQL Server:

```
USE [master]
GO
ALTER DATABASE <DBName> ADD FILEGROUP <[FGName]>
```

Where is the corresponding `.ndf` file created on disk?

When I run that query, it's successful and I am able to find the new file group being added to the `sys.filegroups` table.

But when I run

```
select * from sys.database_files
```

I am not able to find the files created for the new file group. I couldn't find it in the disk as well. What am I doing wrong?

Could somebody help with this..?

Comment: A **file group** as such is just a logical construct inside SQL Server - it is **NOT YET** an actual, physical file on disk. For that, you need to actually **add a file** (using the `ALTER DATABASE .. ADD FILE`) command and specify where to create that file

Comment: @marc_s: Thanks marc , I got it now.. I thought when we add a filegroup, one .ndf file would be created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

In SQL Server you will have to explicitly add the .ndf files to the different filegroups. If you dont mention any filegroup then by default it will be added to primary filegroup.

So whenever you add a filegroup it is just a logical name and it does not have any physical location.

```
use yourDBname
select * from sys.database_files 

ALTER DATABASE yourDBname ADD FILE (NAME = name1, FILENAME = 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\DB11.ndf', SIZE=100MB, MAXSIZE=500GB, FILEGROWTH=50);
ALTER DATABASE yourDBname ADD FILEGROUP BusyTables

select * from sys.database_files
```